# Creating multiple associated records from a single form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a form which creates a Listing - but I want it to create some associated records. My models are structured as follows:

- Listing `has_and_belongs_to_many` Cards (as in business cards)
- Card `belongs_to` Company (a company can have many business cards)

When I submit this form I want to create a Listing, a Card and a Company in one shot. Also validations should be run.

Now I understand that if I want to include a Card field in my Listing form I'll use something like:

```
@card = @listing.cards.build
[...]
fields_for(@listing, @card) do |c|
```

But what should I do if I want to include Company fields in the form? I checked, but `@card.company` is nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**:

building a `card` doesn't automatically create an associated `company`

**Long answer**

The most reasonable way IMHO would be to start with the `company` and create associations around it *even* if you want to create a `listing`.

See it this way:

- `listing` and `company` can exist on their own
- `card` presupposes the existence of a `company`
- a `listing` and a `card` are associated through a join table

Ergo: if you want to create a `listing` that has an associated `card`, you would also need a `company` to which that `card` belongs. Thus we would put the company on top of the hierarchy and do something like this:

```
class CompanyController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def new
    @company = Company.new
    @card = @company.cards.build
    @listing = @card.listings.build
  end
  ...
end
```

Respectively in your nested form you will have the `company` at the top, `card` next and `listing` at last:

```
= form_for @company do |company_f|
  - # company stuff
  = company_f.fields_for @card do |card_f|
    - # card stuff
    = card_f.fields_for @listing do |listing_f|
      - # listing stuff
```

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for. Didn't think about it from this perspective. I was thinking that maybe you could suggest a better title for the question?

Comment: @kitsched I am really flattered. Maybe a title like "initiating and creating multiple associated records in a single form" suits the question? What do you say?

Answer (score 0):

You should use  `fields_for` form helper
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for

Or use gems like
https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form

Comment: I use `fields_for`, but the problem is that the Company resource is nil.

Comment: If a company is defined, just use its id. If it is not there use company.build also

Comment: or you can have a select_tag for company select.

Comment: That's the problem, it is not, basically I want to create a Listing, Card and Company in one shot.

Comment: use company.build, and add more additional attributes for if wit fields_for.

Comment: `l = Listing.new; card = l.cards.build` works well, but if I do: `company = card.company.build` I get NoMethodError: undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass because card.company is nil. As I explained in my question.

Comment: and how do you get `card` var value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69549/discussion-between-kitsched-and-pavel-s).